# python 3 function to check if numbers are odd using %, giving me error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am trying to write a function to see if a number is odd by using a % operator but get an error saying TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

```
num = (input("num > "))
x = num % 1
def OddCheck(num):
    if x == 1:
        print('num',num,'is odd')
    else:
        print(num,'is not odd')

print(OddCheck(num))
```

When I switch %, for *, I don't get any error.

```
num = (input("num > "))
x = num * 1
def OddCheck(num):
    if x == 1:
        print('num',num,'is odd')
    else:
        print(num,'is not odd')

print(OddCheck(num))
```

Comment: `input` returns a string. Using the `%` operator on it tries to do string formatting. Your OddCheck function also doesn't actually check if its input is odd, it checks the value of a global variable. This is probably going to get you a poor grade...

Comment: Incidentally, any number `% 1` is always 0.  You mean to be doing `% 2`.  It also looks like you meant for the `x = num % 1` line to be inside the function, not outside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`input`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string in Python 3.x.  Meaning, you need to explicitly convert the input to an integer:

```
num = int(input("num > "))
```

The second example does not throw an error because multiplying strings by integers is perfectly legal:

```
>>> 'a' * 2
'aa'
>>>
```

---

Also, you need to do `num % 2` to check if `num` is odd:

```
>>> 3 % 2
1
>>> 4 % 2
0
>>>
```

`num % 1` will always return `0`, regardless of the value of `num`:

```
>>> 3 % 1
0
>>> 4 % 1
0
>>>
```

---

Finally, `x = num % 2` should be placed *inside* the function:

```
num = int(input("num > "))
def OddCheck(num):
    ############
    x = num % 2
    ############
    if x == 1:
        print('num',num,'is odd')
    else:
        print(num,'is not odd')

print(OddCheck(num))
```

Otherwise, you will not be checking the argument `num` passed into the function.